# Struts2 ClassNotFoundException: AbstractInterceptor for 2.5.10.1

Tags: java, struts2

I get this stacktrace. It seems it's trying to load an interceptor before the jar itself is loaded. but `com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor` is included in struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar! Should I add an additional dependency on XWork?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor
     [java]     at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:357) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
     [java]     at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:318) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
     [java]     at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:186) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
     [java]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
     [java]     at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:412) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
     [java]     at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:366) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
     [java]     at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:318) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
     [java]     at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:186) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
     [java]     at weblogic.utils.classloaders.FilteringClassLoader.findClass(FilteringClassLoader.java:125) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
     [java]     at weblogic.utils.classloaders.FilteringClassLoader.loadClass(FilteringClassLoader.java:100) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
     [java]     at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:186) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
     [java]     at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:50) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
     [java]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:168) ~[struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]
     [java]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.getClassInstance(ObjectFactory.java:124) ~[struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]
     [java]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:185) ~[struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]
     [java]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:172) ~[struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]
     [java]     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultInterceptorFactory.buildInterceptor(DefaultInterceptorFactory.java:47) ~[struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]
```

Comment: I do not even use Struts in my application and I am getting the same error on Weblogic 12.1.3?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by moving the Struts core 2.5 dependency from the war maven module to the ear module. This was on a Weblogic 12.1.3 application server. I also had to copy struts-tags.tld from struts2-core-2.5.13.jar/META-INF into the web-app's WEB-INF.